# Is it possible to modify a LEFT JOIN to return a null row where there is a match as well as the match?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have a table that represents a hierarchy, as such it has both an `id` and a `parent_id`. There are only two levels to this hierarchy and the parents have null in the `parent_id`. I'm trying to get a record for each item in the hierarchy where the parent has a particular property. For example with this data:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int, parent_id int, property bit);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
    (1, null,    0),
    (2,    1, null),
    (3, null,    1),
    (4,    3, null),
    (5, null,    1);
```

I Want to retrieve:

```
======
| ID |
======
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 5  |
======
```

I can do this using a `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT
   id
FROM
   t
WHERE
   property = 1 AND parent_id is null
UNION
SELECT
   child.id
FROM
   t parent
   INNER JOIN t child
       ON parent.id = child.parent_id
WHERE
   parent.property = 1
ORDER BY
   id;
```

However this scans the table three times. I was trying to optimize this a little so tried this:

```
SELECT
   ISNULL(child.id, parent.id)
FROM
   t parent
   LEFT JOIN t child
       ON parent.id = child.parent_id
WHERE
   parent.property = 1
```

However this just gives me:

```
======
| ID |
======
| 4  |
| 5  |
======
```

Row 3 is not returned because the `LEFT JOIN` does not give a separate row for 3 as it matches the `parent_id` in row 4. Is there any way to modify the `LEFT JOIN` to give the extra row that I need? Is there another way to do this query that does not involve scanning the table three times as the `UNION` method does?

Comment: A join will link two tables, it will not return rows twice.

Comment: The left join is doing two table scans anyway as well

Comment: @Jaques Ok I was wrong the left join does two table scans and the union does three. It is a little more complex as there are indexes involved, but that is not really the point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT 
   ISNULL(child.id, parent.id)
FROM
   t child
   LEFT JOIN t parent
       ON child.parent_id = parent.id
WHERE
   parent.property = 1  OR child.property = 1
   /* you might want to do this instead to be sure to include only the parent nodes 
      with the property set to 1 :
      parent.property = 1  OR (child.property = 1 AND parent.id IS NULL)
   */
```

Returns :

```
ID
3
4
5
```

and gives better performance

Answer (score 0):

This also works, but the execution plan becomes nasty

```
WITH n(id, parent_id) AS 
   (SELECT id, parent_id
    FROM t
    WHERE property = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nplus1.id, nplus1.parent_id
    FROM t as nplus1 
    inner join n on n.id = nplus1.parent_id)
SELECT id FROM n
order by id
```

Comment: Why would you need to use a recursive CTE on this simple hierarchy ? A join is enough and gives far better performances

Comment: Like I said, It also works. I didn't say it is the correct solution. You solution is way more superior than mine. And according to my checks, the performance is actually exactly the same